# How to display a loading screen while doing heavy computing in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I am working on a program that searches the users phone for some date, which takes about 2-3 seconds. While it's computing I want to display a loading screen, so the user knows something indeed is happening. However, when I try to display a loading screen before the computations, nothing is displayed on the screen.

This is what I have:

```
        ProgressDialog loading= new ProgressDialog(this);
        loading.setTitle("Loading");
        loading.setMessage("Please wait...");
        loading.show();

       //search stuff
        loading.dismiss();
```

In addition to this, I have tried putting the ProgressDialog in a thread like the following,

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
              ProgressDialog loading= new ProgressDialog(this);//error here for "this"
              loading.setTitle("Loading");
              loading.setMessage("Please wait...");
              loading.show();
            }
        });
//search stuff
```

but it fails due to the "this" keyword, I believe because its referring to an Activity and not a regular class, but I could be wrong...

How can I get the ProgressDialog to display properly?

Comment: Why are you creating a new Thread to actually show the loading bar rather than creating a new thread to do the heavy processing that you talked about... and use the UI thread (ur current thread ) to show the progress bar etc...

Comment: If you are doing the searching part in a different thread then call `loading.dismiss()` in the end in that thread itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to handle it in this way

```
mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait","Long operation starts...", true);
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

               //Do long operation stuff here search stuff

                try {

                    // code runs in a thread
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (final Exception ex) {

                }
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I almost got it to work with what you gave me, but how can I update a global value in that thread? I keep getting an error stating that it needs to be final, but when I set it to final, I get another error since the only time I set the value is inside the thread.

Comment: @swagantiswag make it a class variable and it will work.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind telling me why it works if its a class variable and not just a function variable?

Comment: @swagantiswag read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class

Comment: I used a runnable instead of a thread and then .run() at the end instead of .start()

Answer (score 0):

Use async task for heavy task. Put your progress dialog code in onPreExecute method progress dialog dismiss code in onPostExecute method and all your heavy task in doInBackground method.

Answer (score -1):

try passing down the context on a new class with your progress bar (this goes on your main activity)

```
NAME_OF_YOUR_CLASS context = new NAME_OF_YOUR_CLASS(getApplicationContext());
```

and on your class call the method like this..(this goes on class)

```
 public Networking(Context c) {
        this.context= c;
    }
```

dont forget to make context a field (private final Context context;)

hope this helps

also idk if this will work but try to extend AsyncTask and use methods to run your progress bar there.

Comment: There is already a huge problem in his solution! sending a context is easy part but do you seriously think its just alright to show a loading on a new thread in android ?