# How to display a Loading Page before opening a Main Window of Application in JavaFx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

I decided to develop my programming skills, so I started  with simple JavaFx project.  I've created a few views and now I want to implemment a Loading Page which can display progress in settings loading.  I tried to create a Secondary Stage which has helped me with displaying   this loading page but I don't know how can I close this stage/scene after loading and run my main stage which is a base to application window/views.
Now I'm using only one stage and I'm switching between all scenes. All views are loading by create a new FXMLLoader and setting as a scene from previous scopes. Can anyone help me?

Comment: No I'm not using anything like that. Is it a big problem? Should I use it?

Comment: Oh, I know what's that but I don't suppose that this framework help me with this problem. Can you describe me how to do it, please?

Comment: Maybe you should create new thread for loading progress window? Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470526/how-to-display-a-loading-screen-while-doing-heavy-computing-in-android

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/SplashScreenTest

Comment: Nice! I've got it! Thanks a lot!